# How can I call collect(Collectors.toList()) on a Java 8 Stream in Kotlin?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, kotlin

I have the some code:

```
directoryChooser.title = "Select the directory"
val file = directoryChooser.showDialog(null)
if (file != null) {
    var files = Files.list(file.toPath())
            .filter { f ->
                f.fileName.endsWith("zip") && f.fileName.endsWith("ZIP")
                        && (f.fileName.startsWith("1207") || f.fileName.startsWith("4407") || f.fileName.startsWith("1507") || f.fileName.startsWith("9007") || f.fileName.startsWith("1807"))
            }
    for (f in files) {
        textArea.appendText(f.toString() + "\n")
    }
}
```

If I call `collect(Collectors.toList())` at the end of filter, I get:

```
Error:(22, 13) Kotlin: [Internal Error] org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: no descriptor for type constructor of ('Captured(in ('Path'..'Path?'))'..'CapturedTypeConstructor(in ('Path'..'Path?'))?')
Cause: no descriptor for type constructor of ('Captured(in ('Path'..'Path?'))'..'CapturedTypeConstructor(in ('Path'..'Path?'))?')
File being compiled and position: (22,13) in D:/My/devel/ListOfReestrs/src/Controller.kt
PsiElement: var files = Files.list(file.toPath())
                    .filter { f ->
                        f.fileName.endsWith("zip") && f.fileName.endsWith("ZIP")
                                && (f.fileName.startsWith("1207") || f.fileName.startsWith("4407") || f.fileName.startsWith("1507") || f.fileName.startsWith("9007") || f.fileName.startsWith("1807"))
                    }.collect(Collectors.toList())
The root cause was thrown at: JetTypeMapper.java:430
```

If I don't do this, I get the `f` with the type `[error: Error]` in my for-loop.

Comment: Also, regardless of the answers below, it looks like you have a compiler bug, you should report this to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com, or check there for duplicates.

Comment: This was an issue, now marked obsolete: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5190

Comment: note:  The bug KT-5190 is fixed in upcoming Kotlin 1.0.1 which will be released soon (it is in final stages of EAP now)

Comment: This issue is now fixed in the released Kotlin 1.0.1 (previously was [KT-5190](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5190)).  No work around is needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** This issue is now fixed in Kotlin 1.0.1 (previously was [KT-5190](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5190)).  No work around is needed.

---

### Workarounds

**Workaround #1:**

Create this extension function, then use it simply as `.toList()` on the `Stream`:

```
fun <T: Any> Stream<T>.toList(): List<T> = this.collect(Collectors.toList<T>())
```

usage:

```
Files.list(Paths.get(file)).filter { /* filter clause */ }.toList()
```

This adds a more explicit generic parameter to the `Collectors.toList()` call, preventing the bug which occurs during inference of the generics (which are somewhat convoluted for that method return type `Collector<T, ?, List<T>>`, *eeeks!?!*).

**Workaround #2:**

Add the correct type parameter to your call as `Collectors.toList<Path>()` to avoid type inference of that parameter:

```
Files.list(Paths.get(file)).filter { /* filter clause */ }.collect(Collectors.toList<Path>())
```

But the extension function in workaround #1 is more re-usable and more concise.

---

### Staying Lazy

Another way around the bug is to not collect the `Stream`.  You can stay lazy, and convert the `Stream` to a Kotlin `Sequence` or `Iterator`, here is an extension function for making a `Sequence`:

```
fun <T: Any> Stream<T>.asSequence(): Sequence<T> = this.iterator().asSequence()
```

Now you have `forEach` and many other functions available to you while still consuming the `Stream` lazily and only once.  Using `myStream.iterator()` is another way but may not have as much functionality as a `Sequence`.

And of course at the end of some processing on the `Sequence` you can `toList()` or `toSet()` or use any other of the Kotlin extensions for changing collection types.

And with this, I would create an extensions for listing files to avoid the bad API design of `Paths`, `Path`, `Files`, `File`:

```
fun Path.list(): Sequence<Path> = Files.list(this).iterator().asSequence()
```

which would at least flow nicely from left to right:

```
File(someDir).toPath().list().forEach { println(it) }
Paths.get(dirname).list().forEach { println(it) }
```

---

### Alternatives to using Java 8 Streams:

We can change your code slightly to get the file list from `File` instead, and you would just use `toList()` at the end:

```
file.listFiles().filter { /* filter clause */ }.toList()
```

or

```
file.listFiles { file, name ->  /* filter clause */ }.toList()
```

Unfortunately the `Files.list(...)` that you originally used returns a `Stream` and doesn't give you the opportunity to use a traditional collection.  This change avoids that by starting with a function that returns an Array or collection.

**In General:**

In most cases you can avoid Java 8 streams, and use native Kotlin stdlib functions and extensions to Java collections.  Kotlin does indeed use Java collections, via compile-time readonly and mutable interfaces.  But then it adds extension functions to provide more functionality.  Therefore you have the same performance but with many more capabilities.

**See Also:**

- [What Java 8 Stream.collect equivalents are available in the standard Kotlin library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34642254/3679676) - You will see it is more concise to use Kotlin stdlib functions and extensions.
- [Kotlin Collections, and Extension Functions API docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html)
- [Kotlin Sequences API docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html)
- [Kotlin idioms](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html)

*You should review the [API reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html) for knowing what is available in the stdlib.*

Answer (score 2):

This is another work around if you are for some reason stuck on older beta version of Kotlin which requires a more brutal workaround...

**Workaround #3:** *(ugly, an old workaround ONLY for old versions of Kotlin)*

Add this *Java* class to your project:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CollectFix {
    public static <T> List<T> streamToList(Stream<T> s) {
        return s.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And this one *Kotlin* extension function:

```
fun <T: Any> Stream<T>.toList(): List<T> = CollectFix.streamToList(this)
```

And then any time you have this case, use this new extension:

```
Files.list(Paths.get(file)).filter { /* filter clause */ }.toList()
```