# How to convert java.util.stream.Stream<Something> into kotlin.Sequence<Something>

Tags: java, java-stream, kotlin

Java 8 Streams are powerful but when parallelism is not needed Kotlin Sequence seems to be simpler to use.

Is there a way to convert a `stream.sequencial()` into a Sequence?

Comment: an example of this is also mentioned under "Staying Lazy" part of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721528/how-can-i-call-collectcollectors-tolist-on-a-java-8-stream-in-kotlin/35722167#35722167

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kotlin has an extension method [`asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.streams/java.util.stream.-stream/as-sequence.html) to convert a Java stream to a Kotlin Sequence. In my experience it was not discoverable until I added an import statement:

```
import kotlin.streams.*
```

Then simply use as expected:

```
val seq = stream.asSequence()
```

Comment: Did they change this import? Doesn't seem to work

Comment: @weston This still appears to exist https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.streams/java.util.stream.-stream/as-sequence.html

Comment: Thanks, I worked this out. The new kotlin project in AS had a dependency on std lib. It shouldn't do that. Removing it fixed it.

Answer (score 18):

You can get an iterator from a stream and then wrap the iterator into a `Sequence`:

```
Sequence { stream.iterator() }
```

**UPD:** Starting from Kotlin 1.1 you can use `Stream.asSequence()` extension (see [Michael Richardson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47889522/869184)), which does the exact same thing as above. The extension is also available for the specialized streams: `IntStream`, `LongStream` and `DoubleStream`.

It is located in `kotlin.streams` package in `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` library (Kotlin 1.2 and above) or in `kotlin-stdlib-jre8` library (Kotlin 1.1 only, deprecated in Kotlin 1.2 and above).

Comment: Great! I see there is also Iterator<T>.asSequence() so I can say:  stream.iterator().asSequence()

Comment: Yes, it's almost the same. The difference here is when the `iterator()` function is invoked on Stream, immediately (`asSequence()`) or lazily (`Sequence { }`).