# Java 8 lambda to kotlin lambda

Tags: kotlin

```
public class Main {
    static class Account {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private Book book;

        public Account(Long id, String name, Book book) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.book = book;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Account> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
        data1.add(new Account(1L,"name",null));
        List<String> collect = data1.stream().map(account -> account.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(collect);
    }
}
```

In the above code I am trying to convert the following line

```
List<String> collect = data1.stream().map(account -> account.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

into kotlin code. Kotlin online editor gives me the following code

```
 val collect = data1.stream().map({ account-> account.getName() }).collect(Collectors.toList())
    println(collect)
```

which gives compilation error when i try to run it.

how to fix this???

or what is the kotlin way to get list of string from list of Account Object

Comment: unresolve reference stream, unresolve reference Collectors

Comment: So the problem is not the lambda. The problem is that Kotlin collections don't have a stream() method. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5175

Comment: what is the kotlin way to get list of string from list of Account Object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call collect(Collectors.toList()) on a Java 8 Stream in Kotlin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721528/how-can-i-call-collectcollectors-tolist-on-a-java-8-stream-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kotlin collections don't have a `stream()` method.

As mentioned in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5175, 
you can use

```
(data1 as java.util.Collection<Account>).stream()...
```

or you can use one of the native Kotlin alternatives that don't use streams, listed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254/what-java-8-stream-collect-equivalents-are-available-in-the-standard-kotlin-libr):

```
val list = data1.map { it.name }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @JBNizet says, don't use streams at all, if you are converting to Kotlin then convert all the way:

```
List<String> collect = data1.stream().map(account -> account.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to

```
val collect = data1.map { it.name } // already is a list, and use property `name`
```

and in other cases you will find that other collection types can become lists simply with `toList()` or to a set as `toSet()` and so on.  And everything in Streams has an equivalent in Kotlin runtime already.

There is no need for Java 8 Streams at all with Kotlin, they are more verbose and add no value.

For more replacements to avoid Streams, read: [What Java 8 Stream.collect equivalents are available in the standard Kotlin library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254/what-java-8-stream-collect-equivalents-are-available-in-the-standard-kotlin-libr)

You should read the following as well:

- Kotlin API reference for [`kotlin.collections`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html)
- Kotlin API reference for [`kotlin.sequences`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html)

And maybe this is a duplicate of: [How can I call collect(Collectors.toList()) on a Java 8 Stream in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721528/how-can-i-call-collectcollectors-tolist-on-a-java-8-stream-in-kotlin)